# Shocking error appears when exporting my application

Tags: android, sdk

I have a big problem with my android application 
the application working fine on the AVD emulator but 
when i try to export it as SDK package many unlogic errors appears 
i think the reason is some thing in the application "AndroidManifest.xml"

and this is my "AndroidManifest.xml" code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlecloudmessaging"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:name="com.example.googlecloudmessaging.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature" ></permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlecloudmessaging.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.googlecloudmessaging"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GcmMessageHandler"></service>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is the unlogic error

```
 "app_name" is not translated in "af" (Afrikaans), "am" (Amharic), "ar" (Arabic), "be" (Belarusian), "bg" (Bulgarian), "bn-rBD" (Bengali: Bangladesh), "ca" (Catalan), "cs" (Czech), "da" (Danish), "de" (German), "el" (Greek), "en-rGB" (English: United Kingdom), "en-rIN" (English: India), "es" (Spanish), "es-rUS" (Spanish: United States), "et-rEE" (Estonian: Estonia), "eu-rES" (Basque: Spain), "fa" (Persian), "fi" (Finnish), "fr" (French), "fr-rCA" (French: Canada), "gl-rES" (Galician: Spain), "hi" (Hindi), "hr" (Croatian), "hu" (Hungarian), "hy-rAM" (Armenian: Armenia), "in" (Indonesian), "is-rIS" (Icelandic: Iceland), "it" (Italian), "iw" (Hebrew), "ja" (Japanese), "ka-rGE" (Georgian: Georgia), "kk-rKZ" (Kazakh: Kazakhstan), "km-rKH" (Khmer: Cambodia), "kn-rIN" (Kannada: India), "ko" (Korean), "ky-rKG" (Kyrgyz: Kyrgyzstan), "lo-rLA" (Lao: Lao People's Democratic Republic), "lt" (Lithuanian), "lv" (Latvian), "mk-rMK" (Macedonian: Macedonia, the former Yugoslav Republic of), "ml-rIN" (Malayalam: India), "mn-rMN" (Mongolian: Mongolia), "mr-rIN" (Marathi: India), "ms-rMY" (Malay: Malaysia), "my-rMM" (Burmese: Myanmar), "nb" (Norwegian Bokmål), "ne-rNP" (Nepali: Nepal), "nl" (Dutch), "pl" (Polish), "pt" (Portuguese), "pt-rBR" (Portuguese: Brazil), "pt-rPT" (Portuguese: Portugal), "ro" (Romanian), "ru" (Russian), "si-rLK" (Sinhala: Sri Lanka), "sk" (Slovak), "sl" (Slovene), "sr" (Serbian), "sv" (Swedish), "sw" (Swahili), "ta-rIN" (Tamil: India), "te-rIN" (Telugu: India), "th" (Thai), "tl" (Tagalog), "tr" (Turkish), "uk" (Ukrainian), "ur-rPK" (Urdu: Pakistan), "uz-rUZ" (Uzbek: Uzbekistan), "vi" (Vietnamese), "zh-rCN" (Chinese: China), "zh-rHK" (Chinese: Hong Kong), "zh-rTW" (Chinese: Taiwan, Province of China), "zu" (Zulu)

Issue: Checks for incomplete translations where not all strings are translated
Id: MissingTranslation

If an application has more than one locale, then all the strings declared in one language should also be translated in all other languages.

If the string should not be translated, you can add the attribute translatable="false" on the <string> element, or you can define all your non-translatable strings in a resource file called donottranslate.xml. Or, you can ignore the issue with a tools:ignore="MissingTranslation" attribute.

By default this detector allows regions of a language to just provide a subset of the strings and fall back to the standard language strings. You can require all regions to provide a full translation by setting the environment variable ANDROID_LINT_COMPLETE_REGIONS.

You can tell lint (and other tools) which language is the default language in your res/values/ folder by specifying tools:locale="languageCode" for the root <resources> element in your resource file. (The tools prefix refers to the namespace declaration http://schemas.android.com/tools.)

[]
```

please any one can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your strings.xml file:

`<string name="app_name" translatable="false">[your_app_name]</string>`

Comment: i try to solve by adding this attribute but after that it came the same error in the 
/google-play-services_lib/res/values/admob_strings.xml
file I don't know that is not the effective solution

Comment: Now I try to add this attribute to all corroborated tags but in this file 
/google-play-services_lib/res/values/common_strings.xml
this solution not working it's giving me an new error

Comment: "common_google_play_services_notification_ticker" is not translated in "be" (Belarusian)

Comment: include `translatable="false"` in all the strings for which it gives error.

Comment: I am already make this but in this file 
 "common_string.xml" file in my "google-play-services_lib" folder
this solution not working it throw a new error

Comment: the error is 
The resource string "common_google_play_services_notification_ticker" has been marked as translatable="false"

Issue: Checks for translations that appear to be unused (no default language string)
Id: ExtraTranslation

Comment: Remove `translatable="false"` from common_strings.xml and go to `Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking` and set `Missing Translation` to `warning or ignore`

Comment: You are welcome.You can remove `translatable="false"` from strings.xml also. It will work.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply disable the translation warnings in eclipse

> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking

Now under Category Correctness:Messages look for `MissingTranslations` and change its Severity from Fatal to Warning or Ignore type. Apply and you may not see these error messages ( would be just displayed as warnings if you select Severity warning)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

How to disable Translations error messages

If you want to suppress the error message then go to,

On Mac OS X,

Eclipse -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking

Solving Eclipse Android Lint Translation error messages

[image]